# Identify incorrectly classified tuples in weka

Tags: algorithm, tuples, classification, weka, data-mining

How to identify incorrectly classified tuples in weka, when we are using crossfold validation?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It causes overfitting if you spy on your errors.

Do not snoop on the test data. If you want to study some missclassifications, further split your data set to also get a *development* set.